# Use three different project code in single one?

Tags: iphone

I  create three application before and now want to use them in single app,
Basically i want to call those application on button click ,

Answer (score 0):

You should share a single AppDelegate for your new project, then use the three apps as UIViewControllers as their own. You cannot fork a new UIApplication from within your code, like you can do with Android's Activity mechanism.

It would need some refactoring, but still will work this way...
You may consider a single "Main Screen" or "Menu Screen" like most apps do, for instance Facebook, Twitter apps, etc...

Comment: Basically problem is that all viewcontroller name are same in my other app

Comment: Then I am assuming they have some stuff in common, If the common parts makes the most of these classes, then merge them and use subclassing to implement the different parts. Or if they dont look alike at all, then i guess only way is to make copies of them and refactor by renaming... 
I cannot see a modular way of doing it, sorry mate...